# Unterschied: Nummer vs. Zahl

Tags: difference, meaning

> **Diese Frage wurde auch hier (auf Englisch) beantwortet:**
> *[Difference between “die Zahl” and “die Nummer” ?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/18437/9551)*

Ein Arbeitskollege hat mir letztens eine Definition von *Nummer* vorgehalten, die ich so nicht kannte. Sinngemäß:

> Eine Ziffer ist ein numerisches Zeichen.
>
> Eine Zahl ist ein numerischer Wert, der sich aus 1 bis *n* Ziffern zusammensetzt.
> Mit einer Zahl kann man Rechenoperationen durchführen (z. B. `13 + 2 = 15`).
>
> Eine Nummer dient der Identifikation und besteht **meistens** aus 1 bis *n* Ziffern.
> Die Nummer kann aber auch Buchstaben enthalten, z. B. Hausnummer 22a.
> Mit einer Nummer kann man nicht (immer) rechnen.

Die Definition von Nummer bezieht sich **nicht** auf Zahlensysteme, die Buchstaben enthalten (wie z. B. das Hexadezimalsystem, in dem `A = 10` gilt).

Wie gesagt, diese Definition war mir neu und ich konnte auch keine Belege dazu finden. Allerdings macht das Sinn, und nun wüsste ich gerne von euch, ob ihr dazu genaueres sagen könnt. Ist das korrekt?

Als Nebenfrage: Ist das in anderen Sprachen wie Englisch auch so?

Comment: Wieso soll man mit Nummern nicht rechnen können? Weil es so leicht ist? Die Seiten meines Buches sind nummeriert. Ich bin auf Seite 324 und das Kapitel endet auf Seite 362 - berechne wieviele Seiten ich lesen muss, um das Kapitel zu beenden.

Comment: korrigiere "Mit nummern kann man nicht (immer) rechnen."  Bsp: Nummernschild 'B-CD-1234', Hausnummer '22a'. Wenn man damit rechnet, kommt nichts sinnvolles raus. Mit "Fortlaufende Nummern" kann man natürlich rechnen (z.B. Buchseiten). Eine fortlaufende Nummer ist ein numerischer Index und damit kann man rechnen.

Comment: Was ist mit den n gemeint? "Eine Nummer besteht meistens aus 1-(n) Ziffern"? Die Nummer 323 - besteht die nun aus 2 oder aus 3 Ziffern? Geht es um die Zahlenlänge, um den Zeichenvorrat oder um was?

Comment: (n) ist eine Unbekannte, die höher ist als ein anderer Wert, auf den sie sich bezieht. 1-(n) heist soviel wie "zwichen 1 und 'mehr als 1'" bzw "mindestens 1"

Comment: @userunknown: Wenn Du die Nummer der Seite 324 von der Nummer der Seite 362 abziehst, erhältst Du keine sinnvolle Seitennummer. Das Ergebnis hat nichts mit der Seite 38 zu tun. Und when Du deine Passnummer mit zwei malnimmst kommt zwar eine Zahl heraus, aber keine sinnvolle Passnummer.

Comment: Der Zweck der Identifikation ist das Wesentliche bei einer Nummer. Eine Zahl steht per se für ein für ein abstraktes mathematisches Konzept, das eventuell mit einer x-beliebige Größe in der realen Welt korrespondieren kann, aber nicht muss. Bei Nummern gibt es hingegen eine Beziehung zu anderen Dingen; z.B. ein Konto zu einer Kontonummer oder ein Haus zu einer Hausnummer.

Comment: @gnasher729: Das habe ich auch nicht behauptet, also widerlegst Du Strohmänner. Von Seite 324 musst Du 38 Seiten weiterblättern, um zu 362 zu kommen, wenn Du nicht falsch gerechnet hast. Zwischen 4 und 6 Uhr liegen auch 2 Stunden und nicht 2 Uhr. Trotzdem nennt man das rechnen.

Comment: Bei Übungen sagt man "Übung Nummer a, b, c...". Zu diesem Kontext würde das Wort Zahl nicht passen.

Comment: Somit ist das Entziffern eines Textes unmöglich, da ein Text Buchstaben und nicht nur Ziffern enthält? ;-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ich würde sagen, diese Unterscheidung ist im Wesentlichen korrekt. Belege liefert z. B. der Duden:

- **[Nummer](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Nummer#Bedeutung1a)**: *Zahl, die etwas kennzeichnet, eine Reihenfolge o. Ä. angibt*. Es ist nach meiner Lesart schon wichtig, dass eine Zahl (im Sinne von Ziffernfolge) der wesentliche Bestandteil ist, aber es können, wie bei Hausnummern, auch Buchstaben enthalten sein, und der Zweck ist kein mathematischer, sondern die Unterscheidung bzw. Kennzeichnung der nummerierten Dinge.
- **[Zahl](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Zahl#Bedeutung2)**: *durch ein bestimmtes Zeichen oder eine Kombination von Zeichen darstellbarer abstrakter Begriff, mit dessen Hilfe gerechnet, mathematische Operationen durchgeführt werden können* – das hatte der Kollege wohl im Sinn, und auch die anderen Bedeutungen von *Zahl* stehen dem m. E. nicht im Wege

Comment: Belege dafür finden sich z.B. auch in Komposita: Hausnummer, Schadensnummer (bei der Versicherung), Rechnungsnummer, Autonummer... da wäre jeweils -zahl nicht möglich.

Comment: Also könnte man sagen, eine Nummer ist ein Index, den man nicht inkrementieren kann?

Comment: @Sempie Jedenfalls kommt beim Inkrementieren nicht notwendig etwas sinnvolles heraus. In meiner Straße "fehlen" z.B. jede Menge Hausnummern, auf die 92 folgt direkt die 96 usw.

Comment: Zum Beispiel im Englischen gibt es nur ein Wort "number" für Zahl, Anzahl und Nummer. 

Natürlich gibt es auch "rationale Zahlen", "reele Zahlen" und "komplexe Zahlen" wo die gegebene Definition nicht passt, und das sind auch alles Zahlen.

Comment: @gnasher729, das sind Zahlenbereiche. Sie sind Elemente des Konzeptes von Zahlen. Wie wir schon festgestellt haben, sind Nummern aber keine Elemente des Konzeptes Zahlen, sondern ein zweites Konzept, dass sich der Zahlen als Element der eigenen Darstellungsform bedient.

Comment: Im Englischen gibt es beispielsweise den Term "numeral" für Ziffer, "number" entspricht sinngemäß unserem Wort für Zahl, lässt sich aber auch für Nummer verwenden, so wie ich das sehe. Immerhin hat die englische Sprache kein 100%iges Gegenstück zum deutschen "Nummer".

Comment: Unterscheidung und Kennzeichnung sind sehr wohl mathematische Zwecke, man denke nur an `x² + px + q = 0`; also kommen Nummern in der Mathematik durchaus vor, aber nicht gleichbedeutend mit Zahlen. Im Nummerieren liegt auch eine Reihenfolge. 3,5 oder 7/4 sind aber keine Nummern, wohl aber Zahlen. Nummern müssen auch keine Zahlen enthalten. `Unter Punkt B der Tagesordnung ...`

Comment: Das Beispiel (x) in der Mathematik ist ein Platzhalter für einen unbekannten numerischen Wert, sogesehen ein Sonderzeichen, keine Nummer. Eine ganze Operation ist schon garkeine Nummer. Dem Rest stimme ich zu.

Comment: @Semple, schau Dir die "Definition" von Zahlen an, die oben angegeben wurde, und die Definition trifft ganz sicher nicht auf die meisten rationalen, reellen, komplexen oder auch nur negative Zahlen zu. In anderen Worten, die Definition ist falsch.

Comment: Natürlich gibt es in der Mathematik Nummern: Wenn der Professor Satz 1, Satz 2, Satz 3 beweist, dann sind 1, 2 und 3 hier Nummern. Weil es Nummern sind und keine Zahlen, können wir nicht Satz 2 und Satz 3 multiplizieren um Satz 6 zu erhalten :-)

Comment: @Semple: Ziffer = "digit". "numeral" wird für die Schreibweise einer Zahl oder Nummer verwendet, zum Beispiel XII und 12 sind die gleiche Zahl oder die gleiche Nummer, aber als "numerals" sind sie verschieden. Und Englisch "number" ist ganz eindeutig und ohne jeden Zweifel die korrekte Übersetzung sowohl for Zahl als auch for Nummer - der Bedeutungsunterschied geht leider bei der Übersetzung verloren.

Comment: @userunknown: Gleis 9 3/4 hat die Nummer 9 3/4.

Comment: @Semple: Ich habe natürlich nicht x gemeint, sondern die Zeichen p, q sind nummeriert.

Comment: @gnasher729: Kommen wir nun zu Ziffer 12 der Tagesordnung. :) Die Sprache ist einfach ein meist unordentlicher Kuddelmuddel. Zu Gleis 9³/4 - das ist doch Harry Potter, oder? Da muss man von einer absichtlichen Verballhornung ausgehen, und sehr vorsichtig sein, dies auf einen allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch zu übertragen. Die Komik basiert gerade auf einer Grenzüberschreitung.

Answer (score 7):

### Kurzfassung

**Zahl**:
Damit kann man Rechnen (addieren, multiplizieren, usw.)

**Nummer**:
Ist ein systematischer Name (eine Bezeichnung für ein Ding)

Diese beiden Definitionen können in manchen Fällen auf dasselbe Objekt zutreffen. (Dann ist etwas sowohl eine Zahl als auch eine Nummer; z.B. die Seitenzahlen in Büchern)

Ergänzend:
**Ziffer**:
Ein Schriftzeichen das man verwendet um eine Zahl zu schreiben. Gelegentlich auch ein Synonym für *Zahl*.

---

### ZAHL

Etwas, mit dem man rechnen kann (im mathematischen Sinn). Also etwas bei dem es sinnvoll sein kann, es in einer Addition oder einer anderen mathematischen Operation mit einer anderen Zahl zu verknüpfen.

Beispiele für Zahlen:

> **3** Die Menge der Eier in meinem Kühlschrank. Wenn ich eines davon aufesse, bleiben noch zwei über: 3 − 1 = 2
>   **29,7** Die Länge eines DIN-A4-Blattes, gemessen in Zentimeter. Wenn ich das mit der Breite des Blattes multipliziere, erhalte ich dessen Fläche.
>   **8.400.000** Das Jahresgehalt des Daimler-Chefs Dieter Zetsche (in Euro). Von dieser Zahl kann man schon einige Ausgaben abziehen, bis das Resultat negativ wird.

### ZIFFER

Eine Ziffer verhält sich zu einer Zahl wie ein Buchstabe zu einem Wort.
Ziffern sind also die Zeichen, mit denen man Zahlen schreibt. Im alltäglichen Dezimalsystem gibt es genau zehn Ziffern, nämlich 0, 1, 2 usw. bis 9. Die Mathematik kennt aber unendlich viele Zahlensysteme. Das kleinste ist das Binärsystem, das nur zwei Ziffern kennt (0 und 1). Gebräuchlich sind auch das Oktalsystem (Ziffern von 0 bis 7) und das Hexadezimalsystem, das 16 Ziffern hat. Im Fall des Hexadezimalsystems müssen zu den zehn »normalen« Ziffern sechs weitere hinzugenommen werden, um ein Set von 16 verschiedenen Ziffern zu erhalten. Das sind üblicherweise die Kleinbuchstaben a bis f oder die Großbuchstaben A bis F.

Beispiele für Ziffern:

> **3** Die erste Ziffer der Zahl π (3,14159265…)
>   **5** Die Ziffer, mit der die aktuelle Jahreszahl (2015) endet.
>   **d** Jene Ziffer des Hexadezimalsystems, deren Wert der Zahl 13 entspricht.

Das Wort »Ziffer« wird manchmal auch als Synonym für »Zahl« verwendet, häufig dann, wenn statistische Größen gemeint sind:

> Die Dunkel*ziffer* liegt deutlich höher.
>   In den Industrienationen sinkt die Geburten*ziffer* seit Jahrzehnten immer weiter ab.

### NUMMER

Eine Nummer ist ein systematischer Name. Mit einer Nummer will man im Allgemeinen nicht rechnen, weil es sinnlos ist, mit Namen Arithmetik zu betreiben. Und weil viele Nummern aus mehr als aus einem Zeichen bestehen, sind es auch keine Ziffern.

Allerdings gibt es Nummern (systematische Namen), die zugleich auch Zahlen sind, mit denen man durchaus auch rechnen kann.

Ein systematischer Name ist ein Name, der nicht nach Belieben vergeben wird, sondern nach einem strengen Schema. Postleitzahlen sind gute Beispiele dafür, obwohl sie eigentlich *Postleitnummern* heißen müssten. Sie haben mehr als eine Stelle, und niemand kommt ernsthaft auf die Idee, die Postleitzahlen zweier Gemeinden zu addieren. Diese Nummern wurden von der Post nach einem wohl durchdachten Schema vergeben und sind nichts weiter als Namen für Zustellgebiete.

Beispiele für Nummern:

> **6a** Die Hausnummer in der Adresse meiner Schwester
>   **WDD2048618M15379X** Eine Fahrgestellnummer
>   **360850401X** Eine ISBN (internationale Standard-Buch-Nummer)
>   **10.10.5** Die aktuelle Versionsnummer meines Betriebssystems

---

### »zählen«, »abzählen«, »durchzählen«, »nummerieren«

Das **Zähle**n (genauer: Das **Abzählen**) ist der einfachste und grundlegendste Vorgang, bei dem reale Objekte mit Zahlen verknüpft werden. Wenn man Dinge abzählt, ist das Ergebnis genau jene Zahl, die wiedergibt, wie viele Dinge man gezählt hat. Im Mathematiker-Jargon: Das Ergebnis des Abzählens ist die Mächtigkeit der Menge, und das ist eine Zahl. (Nämlich eine *Kardinal*zahl)

Eng damit verwandt ist das **Durchzählen**. Das läuft gleich ab wie das Abzählen, allerdings weist man während des Zählens jedem einzelnen Objekt eine bestimmte Zahl zu. Welche Zahl das jeweils ist, hängt also von der genauen Reihenfolge ab, in der man diese Dinge durchzählt. Wenn man die Dinge anders anordnet, erhalten sie andere *Ordinal*zahlen.

Wenn Soldaten beim Morgenappell durchzählen, beginnt einer damit laut »Eins« zu rufen, und jeder andere ruft dann, wenn sein Nachbar seine Zahl gerufen hat, die nachfolgende Zahl. Sinn dieser Übung ist es, festzustellen, wie viele Soldaten auf dem Kasernenhof stehen, denn die Ordinalzahl des letzen Soldaten ist gleichzeitig die Kardinalzahl der ganzen Gruppe. Wenn sich dieselben Soldaten aber am nächsten Morgen in einer anderen Reihenfolge aufstelle, werden die meisten von ihnen eine andere Ordinalzahl als am Vortag rufen (aber am Ende zur selben Kardinalzahl gelangen)

**Nummerieren**
Wenn die Dinge, die man durchzählen will, aber von sich aus bereits eine natürliche Ordnung haben (wie z.B. die Seiten in einem Buch, oder die Tage in einem Monat), tritt der Fall ein, dass beim Durchzählen dieser Dinge (in ihrer natürlichen Reihenfolge) diese Dinge immer dieselbe Ordinalzahl zugewiesen bekommen. Daher kann man diese Ordinalzahl (=*Zahl*) auch als systematischen Namen (=*Nummer*) für das jeweilige Objekt verwenden.

In diesem Fall sind die Zahlen also zugleich auch Nummern. Und man kann deshalb mit den Nummern (den systematischen Namen) rechnen (11 Seiten vor Seite 34; 5 Tage nach dem 12. März), weil diese Nummern in diesem Fall auch Zahlen sind.