# Nummern in Wörtern: bis wie viel?

Tags: word-usage, numbers

Bis wie viel schreibt man Nummern in Wörtern: bis zehn oder bis zwölf?

Hat die Schreibweise mit alter/neuer Grammatik zu tun?

Comment: Übrigens: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/16026/unterschied-nummer-vs-zahl

Comment: Oh, und ich denke, der Ausdruck ist „in Worten“, nicht „in Wörtern“,

Answer (score 5):

Nein, das ist reine Konvention und hat nichts mit Rechtschreib- oder Grammatikreformen zu tun.

Nach [Duden](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Schreibung-von-Zahlen-0) hat man früher entsprechend einer Buchdrucker-Regel Zahlen bis 12 ausgeschrieben und ist erst ab 13 auf Zifferndarstellung gewechselt.

Bei *hundert* oder *tausend* wurden aber auch da schon Ausnahmen gemacht.

Inzwischen gibt es keine feste Regel mehr.

Comment: Ich würde sagen, alle Zahlen die einstellig sind (0-9) ausschreiben: *Ich habe drei Kinder*, und alle die zwei- oder mehretellig sind, nicht ausschreiben: *Ich besitze eine Autogarage mit 27 Autos*

Comment: Die Regel "bis zwölf" kann allenfalls als eine Empfehlung gelten. Selbstverständlich schreibt (und liest!) man lieber "37" als "siebenunddreißig". Umgekehrt wird der Lesefluss auch gestört, wenn plötzlich Ziffern im Text erscheinen, wo es auch 1 simples Wort getan hätte. Wenn jedoch mehrere Zahlen thematisiert werden und "Messwertcharakter" haben, spricht viel dafür sie einheitlich in Ziffern zu schreiben und nicht etwa unterschiedlich für bis/ab zwölf: "Wir produzieren 77 Autos am Tag, nämlich 11 (nicht elf) Autos pro Stunde an 7 (nicht sieben) Fließbändern im Drei-(oder 3?)Schicht-Betrieb"

Comment: In general writing I learned (as German language speaker by nature in the 1990's) to write all numbers until 5 in words, and start with 6 in numbers is fine, but no "need to be".